# How to specify min and max in emmet?

Tags: html, max, min, emmet

I am trying to code a very simple html code using emmet. But I got stuck for specifying min and max value for a input type. I need your help in that So please if any one knows please post it.

I am putting code here:-

This is code I supposed to get

```
<input type="number" name="" id="" min="" max="">
```

Now my emmet is looks like

```
input:number
```

This gives :-

```
<input type="number" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
input:number[min][max]
```

you can also specify initial values like this:

```
input:number[min=10][max=50]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It helped me a lot.